# What is the action hook for save media-form on gallery tab?

Tags: hooks, gallery, media-library

I want to save a meta data to post parent when the media-form on gallery tab is saved( The submission button is "Save All Changes"). Which action hook can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For updates it is `'edit_attachment'` and for new attachments `'add_attachment'`.

There is no action dedicated to images coming from the gallery tab, but you could check the global array `$_FILES`. If there is a `$_FILES['async-upload']` it is *probably* a request from the media popup.

Comment: great! it saved!